# how to set "--token-auth-file=SOMEFILE" flag to apiserver on kubernetes v1.19.0

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#static-token-file says we need to add this flag to use static token authentication but does not show the procedure how to do it.

I have installed kubernetes using kubeadm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have to pass the path where is static token file located on your host machine in directoy so that you can point to that file just like this. Edit the kubeapiserver.yaml file which is located at `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` and add the below flag. Once you edit the yaml file you will see something like this

```
  --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379
  --admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota
  --service-account-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/pubkey.pem
  --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/16
  --allow-privileged=true
  --authorization-mode=RBAC
  --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
  --token-auth-file=/path/where/yourfile/located/which/contain/tokens  # here add your path
  --client-ca-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/cacert.pem
  --tls-cert-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/servercert.pem
  --tls-private-key-file=/var/lib/kubernetes/serverkey.pem
  --address=172.18.11.249
  --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1
  --advertise-address=172.18.11.249
  --audit-log-maxage=30
  --audit-log-maxsize=100
  --audit-log-path=/var/log/kube-apiserver.log
  --v=4
```

Comment: how to pass this file/info to kube-api server is my question ? using which command ?

Comment: the moment i edit that file , My kube-apiserver pod is crashing and none of the kubectl command works and kube-apiserver container is continously restarting  [root@project1-master ~]# kubectl get nodes
The connection to the server 15.250.87.114:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: you just added the token-auth-file right? check the logs of docker container of kube-api-server do ```docker ps``` and get the container id and look for logs using ```docker logs ID```

Comment: i had to add Volumemount & volumes sections as well as mentionted in 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/43075428/3638081